# How send a Js Array in Ajax Updater (prototype)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, prototypejs

```
respostasUsuario = new Array();

respostasUsuario[questao1] = 3; 
respostasUsuario[questao2] = 4;
respostasUsuario[questao3] = 1;

    function corrigir(){

        new Ajax.Updater('content', 'corrigir', {
              parameters: { banana: 10, respostasUsuario :  respostasUsuario }
            });

    }
```

Banana returns ok...**but respostasUsuario no...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function corrigir(){
  var parameters = respostasUsuario;
  parameters['banana'] = 10;
  new Ajax.Updater( 'content', 'corrigir', {
                    parameters: parameters  
                      });
      }
```

Comment: How do you check parameters when you see only 'banana'? Could you give me the source, please?

Comment: Try to use 'var' before 'respostasUsuario' it will be better. But hardly it's the reason. So, what is your callback for request?

Comment: I think it's unnecessary to do *var parameters = new Object()* in this case because you assign *parameters* to object *respostasUsuario*. After this parameters becomes Object too.